# Creating apple JWT token

Tags: c#

Im trying to the Apple App Store Connect API from a .core application.

I currently have

```
var key = <contents of p8 file>;

var credentials = new SigningCredentials(
    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)),
    SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256
);

var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);
header.Add("kid", KeyID);   

var payload = new JwtPayload
{
    { "aud ", "appstoreconnect-v1"},
    { "exp", exp},
    {"iss", issuerID }
};

var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload); 
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var tokenString = handler.WriteToken(secToken);
```

The problem im having is

> Unable to create the SignatureProvider.\nAlgorithm: 'System.String', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey'\n is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: [https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms"](https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms%22)

Answer (score 0):

The p8 file tha you downaload from apple is unencrypted. Using openssl commands you can convert it to .pem file unencrypted and encrypted. You can also extract the public key.

Personallly I created the pem file containing the private key and I used this file for creating the client secret and then and therefore the jwt which I verified in https://jwt.io

Answer (score 0):

Ecdsa is an asymmetric algorithm, and you are using a symmetric key within your signing credentials. You should either use an asymmetric key with Ecdsa or use a symmetric algorithm with the SymmetricSecurityKey.